# Insert data from DB to URL manager

Tags: yii

I want URL manager to process URL with the company name with my CompanyController. To do so dynamically I should get company names from my database.
Now I have such rule (but it's not dynamic):

```
            '<alias:(vector|karnasch|tecnomagnete|ruko|bds-maschinen|exact)>' => 'company/view',
```

(vector|karnasch|tecnomagnete|ruko|bds-maschinen|exact) --> data to this line I want to get from database.

I can get this data (manually establish connection to db), but maybe it's another more beautiful solution with help of Yii functional. Thanks!

Comment: Or "how to make useless sql query"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your [custom `UrlRule`class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes). If you only want to parse incoming URLs you can simply return `false` from the `createUrl()` method. In the `parseUrl()` method you query the DB for your company names and inspect if the current URL matches. If not, you simply return `false` again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to do this, you just have to define the right pattern, e.g. :

```
'contact' => 'contact/form',
// other rules should be set before this one
'<alias:[-\w]+>' => 'company/view',
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters

Comment: problem that your rule will return true for the URL www.site.com/contact

Comment: you just have to set other rules before, you really don't need to query database just for this...